# Promblem with Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) in NetBeans

Tags: java, maven

I'm having a problem with this error when i add an icon to label in java swing. Please help me to sovle this. Thank you very much!
This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.doan.greenbeauty</groupId>
    <artifactId>GreenBeauty</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.doan.greenbeauty.GreenBeauty</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
    
</project>
```

And the errors is:
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project GreenBeauty: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Answer (score 0):

The `pom.xml` does not look right. The `exec-maven-plugin` should not be your project dependency (does *your* code use classes from the plugin?).

How about something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.doan.greenbeauty</groupId>
    <artifactId>GreenBeauty</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties> 
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.doan.greenbeauty.GreenBeauty</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now `mvn exec:java` executes your class. Or, if you want it done automatically during some phase try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.doan.greenbeauty</groupId>
    <artifactId>GreenBeauty</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties> 
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.doan.greenbeauty.GreenBeauty</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execute-after-compile</id>
                        <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How does it relate to using Swing gui editor - I have no idea, though.